how to configure an eventbridge rule to glue crawler?
looking for some help on this. I read some some examples , but still not sure , if i can directly invoke a glue crawler job via s3 object notification . based on what i read, it looks like i can't.
so far , i have  a cloudwatch event rule, that looks for a object creation in s3 bucket.  how can i configure following  glue crawler to be triggered via my cloudwatch event rule? new to terraform , so some code will help
resource "aws_glue_crawler" "example"{
   ....
}

resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_rule" "example" {
    name        = "example-event-rule"
    description = "object creation - S3 bucket"
   
    event_pattern = <<PATTERN
{
  "detail-type": ["AWS API Call via CloudTrail"],
  "source": ["aws.s3"],
  "detail": {
    "eventSource": ["s3.amazonaws.com"],
    "requestParameters": {
      "bucketName": ["example-bucket"]
    },
    "eventName": ["PutObject"]
  }
}
PATTERN
}


Sorry, but StackOverflow is not a free coding service. Please take a look here first: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.
